# D8 - can't view Contributions after upgrade to 5.28.x

Tags: drupal-8

When trying to View a Contribution (any Contribution) I'm getting this error on one of my D8 test sites.

```
Error: Class 'Brick\Money\Money' not found in CRM_Utils_Money::subtractCurrencies() (line 142 of /var/www/drupal/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/CRM/Utils/Money.php)
```

It's still at 5.28.2

Comment: How was it upgraded? It sounds like composer troubles and there may be other stuff off/missing too.

Comment: Can you confirm if you have the fix for the issue https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/1959 or are on 5.28.3?

Comment: Ah this site is on 5.28.2 -> and I see the milestone for 1959 is 5.28.3

Comment: However another site where I can view contributions (same server/same PHP) is on 5.28.2 as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran `root@94ecc520c552:/var/www/drupal# composer update --with-dependencies`  and it's happy now. I can see View Contribution. Not sure why - but all good again. Phew!

Detailed output copied below - nothing about brick / money -> but this did work:

```
root@94ecc520c552:/var/www/drupal# composer update --with-dependencies
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Package operations: 0 installs, 7 updates, 0 removals
  - Updating civicrm/civicrm-core (5.28.2 => 5.28.3): Downloading (100%)         
Download extra files for civicrm/civicrm-core
  - Installing civicrm/civicrm-core:angular (5.28.3): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing civicrm/civicrm-core:angular-bootstrap (5.28.3): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing civicrm/civicrm-core:angular-file-upload (5.28.3): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing civicrm/civicrm-core:angular-jquery-dialog-service (5.28.3): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing civicrm/civicrm-core:angular-mocks (5.28.3): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing civicrm/civicrm-core:angular-route (5.28.3): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing civicrm/civicrm-core:angular-sanitize (5.28.3): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing civicrm/civicrm-core:angular-ui-sortable (5.28.3): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing civicrm/civicrm-core:angular-ui-utils (5.28.3): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing civicrm/civicrm-core:angular-unsavedchanges (5.28.3): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing civicrm/civicrm-core:angular-xeditable (5.28.3): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing civicrm/civicrm-core:checklist-model (5.28.3): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing civicrm/civicrm-core:ckeditor (5.28.3): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing civicrm/civicrm-core:crossfilter-1.3.x (5.28.3): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing civicrm/civicrm-core:crossfilter2 (5.28.3): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing civicrm/civicrm-core:css-color-names (5.28.3): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing civicrm/civicrm-core:d3 (5.28.3): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing civicrm/civicrm-core:d3-3.5.x (5.28.3): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing civicrm/civicrm-core:datatables (5.28.3): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing civicrm/civicrm-core:dc-2.1.x (5.28.3): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing civicrm/civicrm-core:es6-promise (5.28.3): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing civicrm/civicrm-core:font-awesome (5.28.3): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing civicrm/civicrm-core:marked (5.28.3): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing civicrm/civicrm-core:google-code-prettify (5.28.3): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing civicrm/civicrm-core:jquery (5.28.3): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing civicrm/civicrm-core:jquery-ui (5.28.3): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing civicrm/civicrm-core:jquery-validation (5.28.3): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing civicrm/civicrm-core:jstree (5.28.3): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing civicrm/civicrm-core:lodash-compat (5.28.3): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing civicrm/civicrm-core:phantomjs-polyfill (5.28.3): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing civicrm/civicrm-core:select2 (5.28.3): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing civicrm/civicrm-core:js-yaml (5.28.3): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing civicrm/civicrm-core:smartmenus (5.28.3): Downloading (100%)         
  - Updating civicrm/civicrm-drupal-8 (5.28.2 => 5.28.3): Loading from cache
  - Updating civicrm/civicrm-packages (5.28.2 => 5.28.3): Loading from cache
  - Updating drupal/smart_date (2.8.0 => 2.9.0): Downloading (100%)         
  - Updating drupal/webform_civicrm (5.0.0-beta1 => 5.0.0-beta2): Downloading (100%)         
  - Updating nikic/php-parser (v4.6.0 => v4.9.0): Downloading (100%)         
  - Updating drush/drush (10.3.1 => 10.3.4): Downloading (100%)         
Package container-interop/container-interop is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use psr/container instead.
Writing lock file
Generating autoload files
  - CiviCRM asset map
33 packages you are using are looking for funding.
Use the `composer fund` command to find out more!
Scaffolding files for drupal/core:
  - Copy [web-root]/sites/default/default.settings.php from assets/scaffold/files/default.settings.php
```

Ran the database updates.

Oh and now I can see the View Contribution. Strange!
Not sure what that could have been?

Comment: My guess is the autoload files didn't get updated when it was upgraded the first time. Because ... composer.